# formatting using sed in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

My input file is in the following format:

```
5470,
1875566222,
"Antigua"
6,
1588552226,
"Barbados
12,
1488899666,
"Nicaragua"
```

This pattern continues for a thousand records.

Every 3 lines is actually one record. The 2nd value in each record is an ID. And there are only theses three ID's throughout the file.

My objectives are:

a) To format this file so that every record is in one line (i.e.)

```
5470,1875566222,Antigua
6,1588552226,Barbados
12,1488899666,Nicaragua
```

b) As you may have noticed in the above output, I also need the double quotes on the country names removed.

c) I would like to sort this file in descending order based on the value of the first field of each record

d) Write each record into a seperate file if it has an ID. SO I am looking at 3 files, each with a set of records having the same ID.

This may be a lot to ask of a UNIX script. But I would be very thankful if at least a part of this is achievable through UNIX shell scripting.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Why sort when printing everything to separate files?

Comment: You are right Jotne. But I would still like the sorting after it is written into 3 seperate files.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier using awk here:

```
> awk 'NR%3==1{a=$0} NR%3==2{b=$0} NR%3==0{gsub(/"/, ""); print a b $0}' file
5470,1875566222,Antigua
5,1488899666,United Kingdom
6,1588552226,Barbados
12,1488899666,Nicaragua
15,1488899666,United States
```

**EDIT:** To get this output in different files:

```
awk 'NR%3==1{a=$0} NR%3==2{b=$0} NR%3==0{gsub(/"/, ""); p=a; sub(/,$/, ".txt", p); print a b $0 > p}' fil
```

**Sorting each file:**

```
mkdir _tmp
for i in [0-9]*.txt; do sort -nk1,1r "$i" > _tmp/$i; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/"/,x);printf "%s"(NR%3==0?RS:""),$1}' file
5470,1875566222,Antigua
6,1588552226,Barbados
12,1488899666,Nicaragua
```

---

If you like to redirect output to multiple files based on ID:

```
awk 'NR%3==2 {f=$0+0} {gsub(/"/,x);printf "%s"(NR%3==0?RS:""),$1 > f".txt"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should take care of parts a, b and c.

```
$ paste -d "" - - - < file | tr -d '"' | sort -t, -k1 -nr
5470,1875566222,Antigua
12,1488899666,Nicaragua
6,1588552226,Barbados
```

Sure, `awk` will be faster but IMO this solution is much more **readable**.

---

For part d, loop over the lines and write them out:

```
paste -d "" - - - < file | tr -d '"' | sort -t, -k1 -nr | while IFS=, read -r a b c 
do
    echo "$a,$b,$c" >> "$b".out
done
```

Comment: hi dogbane. When i tried this solution in a shell script it replies command not found. Any pointers?

Comment: Do you have `paste` installed on your system. Perhaps try running each part of the pipeline separately to work out which command is not being found.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty similar to the other answers. I had it done first moment but I post it now because I like answers to have explanations:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\",]" ;OFS=","}
     !(NR%3) {country=$2; print id, num, country}
     NR%3==1 {id=$1}
     NR%3==2 {num=$1}' file
   | sort -t"," -k1,1 -nr
```

#### Explanation

- `BEGIN{FS="[\",]" ;OFS=","}` sets field separator as `,` or `"`. Output field separator is set to comma `,`.
- Now it works with `NR`, which stands for number of record. In this case, number of line.
- `!(NR%3) {country=$2; print id, num, country}` if the line is multiple of 3 (that is NR/3 has modulus 0), then catch the value `country` and print to whole line.
- `NR%3==1 {id=$1}` in 3k+1 lines, catch the id.
- `NR%3==2 {num=$1}` in 3k+2 lines, catch the num.
- `sort -t"," -k1,1 -nr` sort numerically the output, reversing it, based on the first column (and just first) and using comma `,` as column separator.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\",]" ;OFS=","} !(NR % 3) {print id, num, $2} NR%3==1 {id=$1} NR%3==2 {num=$1}' file | sort -t"," -k1,1 -nr
5470,1875566222,Antigua
12,1488899666,Nicaragua
6,1588552226,Barbados
```

---

In case you want to create a file every time, do pipe after `sort` like this: `awk -F, '{print > $3".dat"}'`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="[\",]" ;OFS=","} !(NR % 3) {print id, num, $2} NR%3==1 {id=$1} NR%3==2 {num=$1}' file | sort -t"," -k1,1 -nr | awk -F, '{print > $3".dat"}'
```

For a sample file like this:

```
5470,
1875566222,
"Antigua"
6,
1588552226,
"Barbados
12,
1488899666,
"Nicaragua"
18,
148,
"Nicaragua"
```

It returns

```
$ cat  Nicaragua.dat
18,148,Nicaragua
12,1488899666,Nicaragua
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree awk is best for this:

```
awk -F'\"|,' '/[0-9]+/{printf "%s,", $1} /[a-zA-Z]+/{print $2}'
```